# JQuery not running on click

Tags: jquery

Morning fellas, im trying to learn jquery, and from hat i know from js, this should be working, but its not... basically onclick of the submit button, it should change the inner html. anyone with more experience have any ideas?

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        reply();
    })
});

function reply(){
 document.getElementById("#progressBar").innerHTML = "worksbro";
}
```

html:

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

if im not mistaken, this should work. it should change the `progressBar` but the onclick does nothing

To remove some confusion:

```
<div id = "progressBar"></div>
```

all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="theJS.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        reply();
    })
});

function reply(){
 $("progressBar").html("worksbro");
}

</script>


<title>
One neat van page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tableone">
<?php
//connect to db
include 'connect.php';

//start the table float left
cho '<table>';
echo '<tr><td style="background-color:#03899C; color:white; text-align:center;">Driver</td>
<td style="background-color:#03899C; color:white; text-align:center;">Van</td></tr>';

//lets get dem drivers and vans
//actually just the vans, realistically. 
$sql= 'SELECT *
FROM Vans';

//make a table float let with driver name and an info(keep it simple)
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo '<tr id="'.$row['Owner'].'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="more(this.id)">';
    echo "<td style=\"background-color:#FFFC00;\"><a href=#>".$row['Owner']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td style=\"background-color:#FFFC00;\">".$row['Year']." ".$row['Make']." ".$row['Model']."</td>";
  echo '<tr>';      
}

echo '</table>';
?>
</div>

<div id="more">
<div id="edit"></div>
<h1 id="van"><u>More Info</u></h1>
<div id="vanList">
</div><!--end vanList-->
</div>

<div id = "progressBar">
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>

<div id="innactive">
<h3>Innactive Vans</h3>
<table>
<?php
//connect to the database
include 'connect.php';
//get inactive vans
//my brain is mush right now, so bear with me...
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM Vans
";



foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
if (!empty($row['Innactive'])){

echo '<tr><td style="background-color:#03899C; color:white; text-align:center;">Driver</td>
<td style="background-color:#03899C; color:white; text-align:center;">Van</td></tr>';

  echo '<tr id="'.$row['Owner'].'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="more(this.id)">';
    echo "<td style=\"background-color:#FFFC00;\"><a href=#>".$row['Owner']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td style=\"background-color:#FFFC00;\">".$row['Year']." ".$row['Make']." ".$row['Model']."                    </td>";
  echo '</tr>';
}
}



?>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle. If it works, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Assuming you have an element with an `id` of `progressBar`, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4seqe/. Check your console for JS errors elsewhere in code.

Comment: If you are submittin a form and which post backs to itself, the page will be reloaded and you won't see the change.

Comment: Problem is elsewhere. When does that submit button  get created? Does it exist in the HTML when the page is loaded?

Comment: @popnoodles the div already exists when the page is loaded

Comment: Actually I might know what it is.

Comment: @popnoodles i would love you for it... i couldnt see areason it wouldnt work either

Comment: Do you receive any errors? I have copied your code to jsfiddle, and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Dj42m/. Have you included jQuery library in your HTML?

Comment: @tpolyak nope no errors, just doesnt work.. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` 

 that what you were wondering?

Comment: The url is wrong, add http: to the beginning of it, I mean: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @tpolyak i tried adding http:, no dice. if only it was that easy. unfortunatly it may be an issue deeper than what i anticipated, i may need to find a different way to do this, ill post back if i find anything

Comment: @popnoodles added all my code, well the index part,

Comment: You've yet to tell us if you're getting any javascript errors in the console. Hit F12 in most browsers.

Comment: @Jack im using firebug, and there no process that runs on the button click, almost like nothing is happening at all

Comment: Now we have the whole code the problem is clear...  There is no #submitButton in the HTML

Comment: @popnoodles sorry man my bad, the button is there, it is created via php upon an ajax request, the code snippet i originally posted is how it looks in browser in firebug

Comment: I suspected as much but said progressBar in my initial comment not submitButton. I  have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now we have the whole code the problem is clear... There is no #submitButton in the HTML –

"sorry man my bad, the button is there, it is created via php upon an ajax request"

Solution, future event required

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#progressBar').html("worksbro");
    })
});
```

Comment: its not reloading the page, eventually it will run an ajax/php query, but right now, the problem at hand, is getting the darn jquery to work...

Comment: i dont understand what more code would be viable. these are the main parts being ran. all my other js is external. the page has bits dynamically created by php but still, this jquery is very much self relient

Comment: You might have a syntax error before that, you might not have included jquery, you might have a typo in the `<script>` tag, there are lots of possibilities. The one we've all ruled out is the code you've posted being wrong.

Comment: people like you make the internet a better place. Out of curiousty. why did this work? what exactly was the issue? im not one to let copy and paste be good enough :P

Comment: Also, am i going to need this "future event" for everything i run off of this function?

Comment: `on()` in this context does this: apply the given event to all elements that are selected by '#submitButton' that exist or will exist inside the element 'document' which **must** exist now. For elements that do exist at the time the script is run you would use `.on()` but like you would `.bind()` http://api.jquery.com/bind/, e.g. `$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){...})` . Bind is fine to use but it just uses `.on()` so I just use `.on()`.

Comment: "Also, am i going to need this "future event" for everything i run off of this function?" Only for those that don't exist at the time that script is run.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by

```
 $("#submitButton").click(function() {
         $("#progressBar").html("worksbro");
    });
```

Comment: doesn't explain why it's not working (probably down to lack of info in the question) but +1 this is how the code should look.

Comment: @MehdiBugnard To be honest - it's not. As popnoodles said, it doesn't explain why its not working. And if this snipper works for him, so will his old code as well. the problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you have that `progressBar` like this for example:

```
<div id="progressBar"></div>

<button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

then do this instead:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#submitButton").click(function()
    {
        reply();
    })
});

function reply()
{
     $("#progressBar").html("worksbro");
}
```

Comment: Correct, but there is no need to wrap the `reply()` function call in anonomous function.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are submitting a form when clicking the `#submitButton`.

The default action of the form will post back to the page itself, which will result in `#progressBar` having its original value.

Try adding a `<input type="button"/>` element and handle the onclick event like above, or even

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(reply);
});

function reply(){
    document.getElementById("progressBar").innerHTML = "worksbro";
    //the jQuery way:
    //$('#progressBar').html('worksbro');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be many things. Maybe you have some other element in the DOM with the same ID (progressBar) which gets updated instead of the one you're expecting. Will need to see your entire code to see what's wrong exactly.